# How do I add some values to the SQL table without the insert into select statement ?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to add the values to the columns where name=Michael for example it seems there is no way to do that

Comment: I hope you understand why you're getting downvotes. It's almost 2017., and you should have learned how to communicate about your problem by now. This isn't a question.

Comment: In case you have doubts about how to ask a good question I suggest you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to ask that you want to update values in columns of a table in which name = Michael.

For that :

```
update tablename 
set col1='val1', col2='val2', col3='val3' 
where name = 'Michael'
```